# SQL Error [4098] [42000]: ORA-04098 when trying to insert data after trigger

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm making an oracle database, and all inserts in my tables work fine. But after I run the trigger and try to do another inserts, oracle shows an error. This is the table of "Cuenta" and of "Retirada" and insert:

```sql
CREATE TABLE Cuenta (
    fecha_creacion  DATE NOT NULL,
    saldo_actual    NUMBER(20,2) NOT NULL CHECK (saldo_actual >= 0),
    numero_cuenta   NUMBER(10) NOT NULL,
    iban        VARCHAR(24) PRIMARY KEY,
    su_banco    VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL REFERENCES Banco(nombre_banco),
    interes     NUMBER(4,2) CHECK (interes >= 0),
    su_codigo_oficina   NUMBER(4) REFERENCES Oficina(codigo_oficina)
);

CREATE TABLE Retirada (
    codigo_operacion    NUMBER(38) PRIMARY KEY, 
    fecha           DATE NOT NULL,
    hora            TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
    cantidad        NUMBER(20,2) NOT NULL CHECK (cantidad > 0),
    descripcion         VARCHAR(200),
    cuenta_emisora      VARCHAR(24) NOT NULL REFERENCES Cuenta_corriente(iban),
    su_codigo_oficina   NUMBER(4) NOT NULL REFERENCES Oficina(codigo_oficina));

    -- Valores a insertar en Cuenta
    INSERT INTO Cuenta(fecha_creacion, saldo_actual, numero_cuenta, iban, su_banco, su_codigo_oficina)
    VALUES (SYSDATE, 2002.00, 2345678906, 'ES1901821302192345678906', 'BBVA', '1302'); -- Cuenta_corriente
```

And this is the code of the trigger:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER actualizar_saldo
  AFTER INSERT ON Retirada
  FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  -- Actualizar el saldo de la cuenta correspondiente
  UPDATE Cuenta SET saldo_actual = saldo_actual - (SELECT cantidad FROM retirada WHERE codigo_operacion = :NEW.retirada) WHERE iban = (SELECT cuenta_emisora FROM retirada WHERE codigo_operacion = :NEW.retirada);
END;
```

It's supposed to extract money from "Cuenta". And after running the trigger, if I try and do:

```sql
INSERT INTO Retirada (codigo_operacion, fecha, hora, cantidad, descripcion, cuenta_emisora, su_codigo_oficina)
VALUES (9, SYSDATE, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 250, 'Retirada 5', 'ES1901821302192345678906', '1302');
```

Oracle gives me this error, but what it should do is extract 250 from an specific "Cuenta". I can't seem to find why. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Your `CREATE TABLE` statements do not stand on their own; you have `FOREIGN KEY` constraints to tables that do not exist and reference incorrect table names.

Comment: all those tables are created correctly, I just didn't put them in the post because the problem is that I can do inserts correctly in the "retirada" table, but after I run the code of the trigger and i try to insert something in "retirada", it shows that error. The tables you say are, already created correctly and with rows on them created correctly.

Comment: They are not created correctly for other users to be able to help you (even if they are correct for you with the rest of your code); this creates additional barriers for those who want to try to answer your question as they need to debug the problems with the rest of your code from posting incomplete/untested DDL statements. Also, as I mentioned previously, you have `REFERENCES Cuenta_corriente(iban)` when the table is called `Cuenta`.

Comment: yeah but that is because Cuenta specifies into Cuenta_ahorro and Cuenta_corriente. Anyway, the answer you gave me worked, so thank you very much!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You appear to want to use the `:NEW` record rather than trying to `SELECT` from the table:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER actualizar_saldo
  AFTER INSERT ON Retirada
  FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  -- Actualizar el saldo de la cuenta correspondiente
  UPDATE Cuenta
  SET   saldo_actual = saldo_actual - :NEW.cantidad
  WHERE iban = :NEW.cuenta_emisora;
END;
/
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/J__xLgok)